# How to import a CSV file to a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, loops, csv, qtablewidget

I am student programmer and I am using Qt to develop a GUI interface for work and Im having trouble figuring out how I should make this this import function work. A bit of programmers writers block if you will. SO far I have this for code:

```
void InjectionLocationsDialogExpanded::importCSVFile()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, ("Open File"), "/home", ("csv File(*.csv)"));
    QString data;
    QFile importedCSV(fileName);
    QStringList rowOfData;
    QStringList rowData;
    int tempint = 0;
    data.clear();
    rowOfData.clear();
    rowData.clear();
    if (importedCSV.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        data = importedCSV.readAll();
        rowOfData = data.split("\n");
        rowData = data.split(";");
        importedCSV.close();
    }
    qDebug() << data;
    for (int x = 0; x < rowOfData.size(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocationsExpandedDialog->columnCount(); y++)
        {
            ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocationsExpandedDialog->item(x,y)->setText(rowData[]);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that I don't know how to get the settext of each item in the table to reference the next item in the rowData QStringList. I need to increment by one location but I cant use a int++ because that will eventually look for a item in the QStringList that doesn't exist and cause a segmentation fault. I also cant use a for loop to cap the number I need in the location field here because of the current for loops structure. I just cant think of a good strategy for to approach this on. Please only leave constructive comments as I am only interested in learning or accomplishing this task. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Sorry to lose you; I have updated the sentence to make comments plural which was a typo on my behalf. I don't know what you mean by by my rowOfData / rowData definitions being confused. rowOfData is being used to find how many rows of Data I have and rowdata is a list of the data in the rows. As for your loop method I believe I am already doing that? Please elaborate if you will...

Comment: Funny usually comments like that help to filter out comments like these. Thanks for your help Matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you would need to take care of line endings.
This means that your code might not be platform independent if you just check for "\n" in your CSV file.

If I get what you're trying to do, you would have to set the rowData within the for-loop.
So, what I would do then :

```
rowOfData.clear();
rowData.clear();

if (importedCSV.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
{
    data = importedCSV.readAll();
    rowOfData = data.split("\n");
    importedCSV.close();
}

for (int x = 0; x < rowOfData.size(); x++)
{
    rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(";");
    for (int y = 0; y < rowData.size(); y++)
    {
        ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocationsExpandedDialog->item(x,y)->setText(rowData[y]);
    }
}
```

I guess this should do it.
Best regards.

Comment: First Id like to to thank you for your help; I tried this and I received a segmentation fault at first. The reason was because columncount was overstepping its boundaries. I traded it out for rowData.size() and it worked perfectly! You should update your answer for future visitors; Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. I actually didn't check the for-loop condition... edited my post. Thanks for the note.