# loading csv in qtablewidget (Why my code is not working?)

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am self-learner and new to qt(I just want to learn to write program). 
Trying to load the csv file to qtablewidget but it overriding all columns and row with same data. I tried to follow [How to import a CSV file to a QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165183/how-to-import-a-csv-file-to-a-qtablewidget) but i did not get it correctly.

**Code:**

```
QFile file("testData.txt");
QTextStream in(&file);
QStringList setDataInrow;
QStringList rowNumbers;
QString allLine;

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    allLine=in.readAll();
    rowNumbers=allLine.split("\n");
    file.close();

}

QTableWidget *myTable=new QTableWidget();
myTable->setRowCount(rowNumbers.size());


for(int row=0;row<rowNumbers.count();row++)
{
    setDataInrow=allLine.split(";");


    for(int column=0;column<setDataInrow.count();column++){
        myTable->setColumnCount(setDataInrow.size());
        //myTable->item(row,column)->setText(setDataInrow[column]);
        QTableWidgetItem *item=new QTableWidgetItem(setDataInrow[column]);
        myTable->setItem(row,column,item);


    }
}


qDebug()<<"Numbers of row needed:"<<"\n"<<rowNumbers<<"\n";
qDebug()<<"Set following data to each column as per row:"<<"\n"<<setDataInrow<<setDataInrow.size();

window->setCentralWidget(myTable);
window->show();
return app.exec();
```

}

**i am trying to load :**

```
John Kl;34;1335532;CA;0444344
Kuma jo;54;44432;NY;0322355
Lebal ho;24;44022;NY;0110004
```

It should be loaded within 3 rows and 5 columns but it is setting 13 columns . Perhaps i am not able think this correctly. I need your help with some code example so that i can study about it more.

Since my English is not good(Sucks like my codes :)) I have taken an screenshot of the current program which is not working as expected:

http://imageshack.us/a/img801/1601/le59.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setDataInrow=allLine.split(";");
```

You do this once for each line. But you don't split the line, as you intended, but each time the whole file content.

Edit: 
Don't split allLine. You have already a QStringList, which contains your lines: rowNumbers.

This you must split.

```
for(int row=0;row<rowNumbers.count();row++){
  QStringList rowCells = rowNumbers.at(row).split(";");
  .....
}
```

I hope this gives you the idea. No guarantee for details.

Edit 2:

When you do

`setDataInrow=allLine.split(";");`

your stringlist contains:

John Kl 34 1335532 CA 0444344 Kuma jo 54 44432 NY 0322355 Lebal ho 24 44022 NY 0110004.

This is the whole text in your file. The line breaks do not matter. They are just another character. You add all this in one row. And you do it three times.

What you want is first split the text into lines. You already do this here:  `rowNumbers=allLine.split("\n");`

With your example data the rowNumbers stringlist contains three entries. Each entry one line from your file. **These** lines you have to split.

Comment: Mind explaining that how i can do this please?

Comment: QTableWidgetItem *item=new QTableWidgetItem(rowCells[column]); myTable->setItem(row,column,item); counting only first line. This seems easy but i don't know why i am completely stuck to understand this.

Comment: First i want to thank you for fast reply with helping post. Perhaps it would be really more helpful for me if you don't mind to post a working code so that i can figure it out that how the code is working(Maybe it is problem for my Bad ENGLISH). My experience in Qt/gui programming is only few days , this is why i am getting stuck always(Even for simple thing). Thanks again for helping me !

Comment: Is it already not splitting ?  If i do QStringList rowCells = rowNumbers.at(row).split(";"); then rowCells holds the first line : ("John Kl", "34", "1335532", "CA", "0444344") and setting to first row correctly. I just can't go to the next line. This is always happening when i am splitting the string, Confused!